# How can I get the value of localstorage at ngOnInit

Tags: angular6

I need to display the username if the user is logged in. I have stored the username and token both to the localstorage.

How can get the this user at the ngOnInit of navbar that I can display at the html.

Here are my codes.

### navbar.component

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

    public loggedIn: boolean;
    public user: any;

    constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._authService.authStatus
            .subscribe(
                value => {
                    this.loggedIn = value

                }
            );
    }
```

### auth.service

```
export class AuthService {

    private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this._tokenService.loggedIn());
    //loggedIn change then change authstatus
    authStatus = this.loggedIn.asObservable();

    changeAuthStatus(value: boolean) {
        this.loggedIn.next(value);
    }

    constructor(private _tokenService: TokenService) {
        if (this._tokenService.loggedIn() == true)
            this._tokenService.getUser();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@nas give a try to this,

Here for the first time we will store the data in the **`localstorage`** and if the data is already there for the user we will use it.

> **In AuthService**

```
constructor(private _tokenService: TokenService) {
        if (this._tokenService.loggedIn() == true)
            this._tokenService.getUser();
         else{
             localStorage.setItem('Authentication',(set your Authentication token Value)); //headers.get('Authorization')
             localStorage.setItem('login',(set your login boolean Value));
           );
         } 
    }
```

> **In Navbar Component**

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

    public loggedIn: boolean;
    public user: any;

    constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
     this.loggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem('login');
     //use this loggedIn variable to check whther user login status 
      }
  }
```